# Typescript - Determine object subtype from union type by checking the presence of some properties

Tags: typescript

I need to display a carousel of items of two possible types (`FirstType`, `SecondType`). My carousel component requires an array as input, so I declared the items as the array of the union

```
type FirstType = {
  a: 'first',
  b: number
}

type SecondType = { 
  b: string
}

type Items = (FirstType | SecondType)[]
```

Now in my render function I get an Item of type `FirstType | SecondType`. I could identify the type by checking the presence of the `a` key, that is a constant on `FirstType`:

```
const renderItem = (item: FirstType | SecondType) => {
  if (item.a === 'first') {
    // Here I know that item is FirstType
  } else {
    // Here I know that item is SecondType
  }
}
```

But this code gives me error:

> Property 'a' does not exist on type FirstType | SecondType

How should I perform this check according to typescript?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgSwE4GcQBVKwLwwN7AwwCGAXDAOQBmyaFANITAEbkB2ArgLbNRIzAAvsFBYYAZSgBjAPZsAJpmgxcBIkVYw0SBGwDmQkbLZoYSKAr4BJEFC4qYACgS2u5RKgxiAPhOlzFLABKFQA+fCYEKicXOwA6YhVsXGpaEAoQtXUAemyYAAk+WCsYAGs2GQB3GBAAC2IQGFj7BBR4NKUoJkEYKAAbFFgsolyCopgS8qqa+sbmprbJY0DobqEgA)

Comment: `if ('a' in item) {`

Comment: If only the presence of `a` matters then all you need is to change the conditional to `if ('a' in item)` as Buczkowski mentioned. However if the value matters (it has to be `'first'`) then you need a custom type-guard as spender's answer describes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the safest way to do this is with a custom [type-guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```
function isFirstType(item: FirstType | SecondType): item is FirstType {
  return (item as FirstType).a === "first"; //or however you want to differentiate
}
```

then

```
const renderItem = (item: FirstType | SecondType) => {
  if (isFirstType(item)) {
    // item is narrowed to FirstType
  } else {
    // item is narrowed to SecondType
  }
}
```